# Folders to include to scan .mp3 files in Android

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I have a hybrid android app, and i am trying to scan .mp3 files in my device.
I am using cordova file plugin for this purpose.

The problem here is i am unable to find my .mp3 files in Download folder.
These are the directories i am scanning recursively, I am able to find my files in other folders such as Ringtones folder.

```
    cordova.file.dataDirectory,
    cordova.file.documentsDirectory,
    cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
    cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory,
    cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,
    cordova.file.externalDataDirectory,
    cordova.file.sharedDirectory,
    cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory
```

Is there any other folder structures i need to include to scan the files ?

Comment: Your'e trying to search mp3 files from a folder?

Comment: I am trying to scan all the .mp3 files in an Android device and show those in a list. I am wondering if that is even possible !

Comment: why don't you try this with simple java?

Comment: How is it different using Java ? I am assuming the folders to scan should be the same ?

Comment: I'm writing a code snippet for you

Comment: hi, try this code and let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can get all mp3 files in directories and sub-directories by using this

```
ArrayList<File> files = nenw ArrayList<>();

public void getFiles(String directoryName) {

    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()&&file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

}
```

And permission needed to read storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```